# What is wrong with \ifnum#1=0.09\relax?

Tags: pstricks, conditionals

The following code does not compile with the following error message

> Missing `=` inserted for `\ifnum`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}

\psset{linewidth=.5\pslinewidth}
\psset{xunit=2cm}

\newcommand\FixedScale[1]{%
    \multips(0,0)(.1,0){\the\numexpr10*#1+1\relax}{\psline(0,0)(0,-3pt)}
    \multips(0,0)(.5,0){\the\numexpr2*#1+1\relax}{\psline(0,0)(0,-6pt)}
    \multips(0,0)(1,0){\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{\psline(0,0)(0,-9pt)}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{\uput[-90](\i,-5pt){$\i$}}
}

\newcommand\VernierScale[2][0.09]{%
    \rput(#2,0){%
    \psset{xunit=#1,linecolor=red}%
    \multips(0,0)(1,0){11}{\psline(0,0)(0,3pt)}%
    \multips(5,0)(5,0){1}{\psline(0,0)(0,6pt)}%
    \multips(0,0)(10,0){2}{\psline(0,0)(0,9pt)}%
    \ifnum#1=0.11\relax
        \multido{\i=0+5}{3}{\uput[90](\i,8pt){\tiny$\the\numexpr10-\i\relax$}}
    \else
        \multido{\i=0+5}{3}{\uput[90](\i,8pt){\tiny$\i$}}
    \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.00+0.01}{21}{%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-.5)(2,.55)
\FixedScale{2}
\VernierScale[0.09]{\n}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

What is wrong with `\ifnum#1=0.09\relax`?

Comment: there is no need for using decimals here.

Comment: @Herbert: Yes. But the value passed to `\VernierScale` semantically represents the length of two consecutive marks on the vernier scale. I have to adopt this convention to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like

```
\ifdim#1pt=0.09pt\relax
```

As mentioned in the other answers, `\ifnum` tests integer values.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\testing#1{%%
  \ifdim#1pt<0.09pt\relax
    SMALL!
  \else
    not so small
  \fi
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \testing{10}

  \testing{0.001}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Thanks for other answers (with up votes done). But the last in won!

Comment: +1 although I'm not sure offering helpful advice as opposed to answering the question as posted is really allowed:-)

Comment: (+1) I don't care if this answered the question - it answered mine!

Answer (score 16):

```
\ifnum#1=0.09\relax?
```

tests if the number passed as `#1` is `0` and if it is, it expands to `.09\relax`

A *number* is an integer.

Answer (score 6):

Read  `\if_integer_number#1=another_integer_`
and *not* floating point numbers.
Use values as percentage:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\psset{linewidth=.5\pslinewidth,xunit=2cm}

\newcommand\FixedScale[1]{%
    \multips(0,0)(.1,0){\the\numexpr10*#1+1\relax}{\psline(0,0)(0,-3pt)}
    \multips(0,0)(.5,0){\the\numexpr2*#1+1\relax}{\psline(0,0)(0,-6pt)}
    \multips(0,0)(1,0){\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{\psline(0,0)(0,-9pt)}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{\uput[-90](\i,-5pt){$\i$}}%
}

\newcommand\VernierScale[2][9]{%
    \rput(#2,0){%
    \psset{xunit=\dimexpr#1\psunit/100,linecolor=red}%
    \multips(0,0)(1,0){11}{\psline(0,0)(0,3pt)}%
    \multips(5,0)(5,0){1}{\psline(0,0)(0,6pt)}%
    \multips(0,0)(10,0){2}{\psline(0,0)(0,9pt)}%
    \ifnum#1=11\relax
        \multido{\i=0+5}{3}{\uput[90](\i,8pt){\tiny$\the\numexpr10-\i\relax$}}
    \else
        \multido{\i=0+5}{3}{\uput[90](\i,8pt){\tiny$\i$}}
    \fi
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.00+0.01}{21}{%
\begin{pspicture}(0,-.5)(2,.55)
\FixedScale{2}
\VernierScale[9]{\n}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```