Set all numbers greater than "X" bold, for decimal numbers
This is a follow up question to Set all numbers greater than "X" bold.
How can I make it work for decimal numbers?
Or if I have a mix of integer numbers and decimal numbers?
Indeed, if I try the same solution for decimal numbers, it does not work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\setmaxnum}[1]{%
    \gdef\maxnum{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\numtest}[1]{%
    \ifnum#1 > \maxnum
        $\mathbf{#1}$%
    \else
        $#1$%
    \fi%
}


\begin{document}

\setmaxnum{0.5}
\begin{tabular}{r}
    \numtest{0.29}\\
    \numtest{0.50}\\
    \numtest{0.72}\\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}

I get the following output:


\ifnum tests against integers, it does not understand decimals. You can circumvent this by using \ifdim and add pt to the decimal number. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135492

Thanks a lot, by using the following, it worked:
    \gdef\maxnum{#1pt}%
}
\newcommand{\numtest}[1]{%
    \ifdim#1pt > \maxnum
        $\mathbf{#1}$%
    \else
        $#1$%
    \fi%
}```

You can't compare decimal numbers with \ifnum, that only compares integers.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\setmaxnum}[1]{%
    \gdef\maxnum{#1}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\numtest}{m}
 {
  \fp_compare:nTF { #1 > \maxnum } { $\mathbf{#1}$ } { $#1$ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\setmaxnum{0.5}
\begin{tabular}{r}
    \numtest{0.29}\\
    \numtest{0.50}\\
    \numtest{0.72}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Thanks a lot!! I can see it is a bit different syntax from \ifnum or \ifdim#1pt ...Something new to learn today :-)
